# How to define schema name in @MappedEntity annotation for r2dbc

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, micronaut, r2dbc

I have kotlin & Micronaut application connecting to postgresql using `r2dbc` for reactive approach

```
r2dbc:
  datasources:
    default:
      schema-generate: NONE
      dialect: POSTGRES
      url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/mydb
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
```

I have the table called Customer inside database `mydb` and schema `myschema`, but while using the [@MappedEntity](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/2.2.1/api/io/micronaut/data/annotation/MappedEntity.html) we can only define the table name. Since table is inside of `myschema` the application is throws entity does not exist

> 15:26:15.455 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] ERROR i.m.h.n.stream.HttpStreamsHandler - Error occurred writing stream response: relation "customer" does not exist
> io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: relation "customer" does not exist

how to define schema name in `MappedEntity` annotation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do it is, you can define the current schema in url using query parameter

```
url: r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/mydb?currentSchema=myschema
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA’s ‘@Table’ as a workaround.